# How can the gsutil cp command copy files older than x minutes?

Tags: powershell, rsync, cp

The current Powershell script used to archive files and subdirectories recursively to a cloud bucket is as follows:

gsutil rsync -u -r -C M:\backups gs://archive-bucket

https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/gsutil/commands/cp

This works fine, however I need a filter to only affect files older than x minutes. Based on the documented feature (see link above) of being able to pipe in a file list, I'd like to apply the timestamp rule to generate a filtered list of all files and subdirectories under M:\backups recursively with some script represented by the placeholder "list_generator" into via -I, the standard input, provided by using cp instead of rsync, roughly like this:

list_generator | gsutil -m cp -n -r -c -I gs://archive-bucket

I presume in the above that the argument -r won't be needed as the recursive action will be relocated into the preceding routine represented by list_generator, while the -n and -c arguments need to be retained to prevent destination overwriting and provide error handling.

Answer (score 1):

Your question boils down to how to get a list of the paths of those file in the directory tree of `M:\backups` whose last-modified timestamp (`LastWriteTime`) is older than x minutes ago:

```
$cutoffDate = (Get-Date).AddMinutes(-20) # example: 20 minutes

Get-ChildItem -File -Recurse M:\backups | 
  Where-Object LastWriteTime -lt $cutoffDate |
    ForEach-Object FullName |
      gsutil -m cp -n -c -I gs://archive-bucket
```

Note:

- In *Windows PowerShell*, you'll have to set preference variable `$OutputEncoding` to the character encoding that `gsutil` expects, so that file names with non-ASCII characters are properly passed; in *PowerShell [Core] 6+*, `$OutputEncoding` defaults to UTF-8.
- In *PowerShell [Core] 6+*, the `ForEach-Object FullName` command is no longer required, because the [`System.IO.FileInfo`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.IO.FileInfo) instances output by `Get-ChildItem` then *consistently* implicitly stringify to the value of their `.FullName` properties.